# Linux: open .do files with Stata

Tags: linux, unix, stata

I would like to select Stata as the default program to open `.do` files.

On Linux (Ubuntu), Stata scripts `.do` are associated with plain text format like `.txt`, which means that when I select Stata in "open with" and click on "remember", it also opens .txt files with Stata.

Is there a way to distinguish `.do` files from others in Linux ?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program

Comment: You may get a better answer at https://askubuntu.com since it is Ubuntu that decides what Stata opens.